# java spring error adding object in Database

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc

I'm trying to insert a row in database but when save the object i get this error :

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation
>   of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'SITE_NAME_UNIQUE'. Cannot insert duplicate
>   key in object 'dbo.SITE'. The duplicate key value is (114,
>   TEST30042015SITEREQUEST).

But this value doesn't exist in database.
Does anybody have an idea ?

script creating the table dbo.site, generated by sql server managment

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SITE](
[SITE_ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
[SITE_BUSINESS_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[SITE_STATUS_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[SITE_COUNTRY_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[SITE_NAME] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
[SITE_ADDRESS] [varchar](250) NULL,
[SITE_LOCAL_IT] [bigint] NULL,
[SITE_RIF] [bigint] NULL,
[SITE_USER_NUMBER] [bigint] NULL,
[SITE_LOCAL_IT_PHONE] [varchar](20) NULL,
[SITE_SUBNET] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
[SITE_ANALOG_PHONE_NUMBER] [varchar](20) NULL,
[SITE_COMMENT] [varchar](400) NULL,
[SITE_ENTITY_CODE] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[SITE_INVOICE_CODE] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[SITE_LOCAL_CONTACT] [bigint] NULL,
[SITE_END_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [SITE_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[SITE_ID] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [SITE_NAME_UNIQUE] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
[SITE_COUNTRY_ID] ASC,
[SITE_NAME] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SITE]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [SITE_BUSINESS_FK] FOREIGN KEY([SITE_BUSINESS_ID])
 REFERENCES [dbo].[BUSINESS] ([BUS_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SITE] CHECK CONSTRAINT [SITE_BUSINESS_FK]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SITE]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [SITE_COUNTRY_FK] FOREIGN KEY([SITE_COUNTRY_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[COUNTRY] ([CTRY_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SITE] CHECK CONSTRAINT [SITE_COUNTRY_FK]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SITE]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [SITE_STATUS_FK] FOREIGN KEY([SITE_STATUS_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[STATUS] ([STA_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SITE] CHECK CONSTRAINT [SITE_STATUS_FK]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SITE]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [SITE_USER_2_FK] FOREIGN KEY([SITE_RIF])
REFERENCES [dbo].[USERS] ([USER_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SITE] CHECK CONSTRAINT [SITE_USER_2_FK]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SITE]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [SITE_USER_3_FK] FOREIGN KEY([SITE_LOCAL_CONTACT])
REFERENCES [dbo].[USERS] ([USER_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SITE] CHECK CONSTRAINT [SITE_USER_3_FK]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SITE]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [SITE_USER_FK] FOREIGN KEY([SITE_LOCAL_IT])
REFERENCES [dbo].[USERS] ([USER_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SITE] CHECK CONSTRAINT [SITE_USER_FK]
GO
```

this function add my object in db :

```
@Override
public void saveSite(ISite siteObj){
    Assert.notNull(siteObj);
    merge((Site) siteObj);
}
```

Comment: As the error suggest that there is already one site exist in table with the same name you are trying to insert

Comment: or that you try to insert 2 rows with the same key

Comment: Please add create script for dbo.SITE table or at at least say what columns included in SITE_NAME_UNIQUE.

Comment: @Aツ yes but the value doesn't exist in the database and the key is generated automatically with the last id normally

Comment: provide us with a ddl and whatever code inserts into the table, pls

Comment: I added the script generated by sql server

Comment: and now the insert pls. :)

Comment: I make that in my dao (post edited) :) i can share when i fill my object if necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a unique constraint on the combination of [SITE_COUNTRY_ID] and
[SITE_NAME].

You are trying to insert a row with a SITE_NAME of 'TEST30042015SITEREQUEST' and a SITE_COUNTRY_ID of 114 when one already exists

OR

You are trying to update a existing row in a way that will violate this constraint.

Comment: I don't have any same row. and I want to make an insert in fact. in spring i make a merge with a new site and itnormally should insert a new row in DB. When  I make an insert or a merge manually in DB it's working

Comment: I tried to save two times the site. one time when I called directly the dao save function of the site and another when I called the dao save function of my other object that contain the site